# Fullcalendar does not render correctly onload

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, kendo-tabstrip

We are using Fullcalendar V5 in Asp.net Core.

We are also using Kendo UI. Our fullcalendar is inside of a "kendo-tabstrip" -> "tabstrip-item" control, if that matters.

Our fullcalendar events are fetched from a controller using Axios(), then the callback renders the events etc...

The problem we have is that when the page loads the first time, the calendar renders in a 1x1mm area in the top left of the calendar div. Instead of full screen as it should.

If I click the previous month button or have a button that does a "calendar.render()", then the calendar renders correctly in a full screen and it renders correctly when going to next or previous months.

Basically, the calendar renders fine after I do a manual "calendar.render()".

What causes this? How can I fix or work around?

I have included my fullcalendar code and an image of how my fullcalendar renders when the page loads.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        height: 'auto',
        expandRows: true,
        headerToolbar: {
                    right: "today",
                    center: "title",
                    left: "prevYear,prev,next,nextYear customButton1,customButton2"
                },
        customButtons: {
                    customButton1: {
                        text: 'customButton1'
                    },
                    customButton2: {
                        text: 'customButton2',
                        click: function() {
                            calendar.render();
                          }
                    }
                },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            var urlString = myapp.url.build("GetFCEvents", "MyController", id)
            axios.get(urlString + "?Id=" + Id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    successCallback(response.data);
                })
        },
        eventContent: function (info) {
            let idname = `chart-${info.event.id}`
            const chartTag = `<div id="${idname}"></div>`;
            return {html: chartTag};
        },
        eventDidMount: function(info) {
            let idname = `chart-${info.event.id}`
            const chartTag = `<div id="${idname}"></div>`;
            generateMyChart(idname);
        }
    });
    calendar.render();
});
......other functions......
 </script>
```

[image: this is how my fullcalendar renders when page loads the first time]

Comment: `Our fullcalendar is inside of a "kendo-tabstrip" -> "tabstrip-item" control, if that matters`...probably, yes. If the calendar renders before the element it's within, you need to render it again to make it show properly (because it judges its size based on the containing element). So if the tab is created using JS, and/or the tab the calendar is in starts off hidden, then you'll need to make sure you don't render the calendar until the tab is shown. Just glancing at the Kendo docs (I haven't used it myself), you might be able to make use of the tabstrip's `show` event for that.

Comment: That did it. I made  var calendar a global, then add "on-show='onShow'" on the kendo-tabstrip. In the onShow() I did a calendar.render(). This fixed the problem. Thanks